# CSS layout with flex

Tags: css

So I have this style that looks differently in chrome and firefox...
I want to have this large rectangle area that would be in a way the main area of the page, and then there would be several smaller divs aligned into columns with flex.

my current page:

```
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div id="mainArea" class="mainArea">
        Main area
    </div>
    <div class="area ">
        asdf
    </div>
    <div class="area ">
        asdf
    </div>
    <div class="area">
        asdf
    </div>
    <div class="area">
        asdf
    </div>
    <div class="area">
        asdf
    </div>
</div>
```

and current css:

```
.area {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /*border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px #303030;*/
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
    width:12em;
    min-height:12em;
    display:block;
}

.mainArea {
    display:block;
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding:5px;
    /*box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px 1px #303030;*/
}

.flexContainer {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-direction: column wrap;
}
```

for now when I start it in chrome it looks pretty much ok, except that spaces between columns are enormous. I already tried doing some weird stuff with padding and margins, but nothing helps. Then, when I start it in firefox, the spaces between columns are ok, but each div is in a separate column :(
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesnt support Flex  out of the box.

type about:config   in firefox  address field

layout.css.flexbox.enabled

set that property to True.  then it will work.

```
  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
```

`-box`  and `-flexbox`  are not used anymore.

its only Flex now.. Go with:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flex;
display: -o-flex;
display: flex;
```